# Shuffling a table of images in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a table of cards that I can shuffle and sort with no problem but when I try to create the table from an array the table works fine but the shuffle function doesn't work anymore.  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
//Create table works fine with cards all in order
document.writeln('<table border = 1 align = "center" >');
for(var j=0; j<cardSet.length; j++){
    if(j%13==0 && j!==0){
    document.writeln('</tr><tr>');
    }
    document.writeln('<td ><img id = "'+ cardSet[j].id +'" src="' + cardSet[j].src + '" /></td>');
}
document.writeln('</tr></table>');

//shuffle function that works of with a manually created table but not with the code above
function shuffleCards() {
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        cardSet[i] = i;
        for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
            rndCard1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*SIZE);
            rndCard2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*SIZE);
            shuffleTemp = cardSet[rndCard1];
            cardSet[rndCard1] = cardSet[rndCard2];
            cardSet[rndCard2] = shuffleTemp;
        }
        for(i=0; i<cardSet.length; i++) 
            cardSet[i].src = document.getElementById(i).src;
}
```

Comment: This code example doesn't look complete, can you explain where you're calling `shuffleCards` please?

Comment: Is the document.writes in a function you call after load? If so, change to `var table = ""; for ......{ table+="..." } document.getElementById("somecontainer").innerHTML=table:`

Comment: Also please look in the console (F12) for errors

Comment: Also `cardSet[i] = i;` will replace the item at the index with the number

Comment: Sorry, meant to say I'm calling the function from a button click buttonDiv.innerHTML='<input type="button" value="Shuffle" onclick="shuffleCards();"/>';

Comment: This shuffle also works perfectly for an array of numbers but I just can't get it to work for images.